# event.preventDefault() for BrowserWindow events close/minimize/maximize not working in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron

I am trying to override the default behaviour of `close`, `minimize` & `maximize` events of the electron browser window. I am getting those events but by `event.preventDefault()` is not working. I don't want window close/minimize/maximize buttons to be disabled but rather to perform some own action. I am using **Electron v13.1.2**, **Chromium v91.0.4472.77**, **Node v14.16.0**, **macOS Big Sur v11.2**.

Your reply is highly appreciated.

*Code Snippet:*

```
win.on('maximize', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log('This is maximize event')
  // Do something else
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers may not let you override that functionality, as that is a direct application / OS action. Plus as a security thing, you wouldn't want to prevent users from closing a web page or an application.

To try to override maximize or minimize, you could try using window.resize?

If it were me, I would try to keep a variable of the window's width and height, and then when they maximize I would reset the window back.

```
    var x = window.screenX, 
        y = window.screenY,
        width:window.innerWidth,
        height:window.innerHeight

    window.moveTo(x, y);
    window.resizeTo(width, height)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your solution seems good but I can't use the suggested approach as I have to stop the behaviour of minimize/maximize/close.